# PHP - Captcha generating wrong character length

Tags: php

I have this captcha script that should generate a length of 4 characters. It does that - most of the times. Although, sometimes, it will generate 3 letters instead of 4. I simply can't find the error.

This is the script to generate length:

```
  $_chars = "0123456789ZXCVBNMASDFGHJKLQWERTYUIOP";

    for($l = 0; $l<4; $l++){


        $temp = str_shuffle($_chars);


        $char = mt_rand(0, strlen($temp));


        $_charcode .= $temp[$char];


    }
```

Comment: You don't need to have two random methods. Either you shuffle or take a random element. No point in doing both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `max` parameter (second ) to your random function should be 1 less than the length of your string because indexes start at 0, and you are using that index for an array later in your code.

```
$char = mt_rand(0, strlen($temp));  // Goes out of bounds on some runs
```

should be

```
$char = mt_rand(0, strlen($temp)-1);   // This way you wont get a blank one
```

Here is a fiddle with 500 runs.

[**Fiddle**](http://codepad.org/PjmmTpgV)